# Vertical time line

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I am developing an application using UWP framework. I need to build a vertical timeline as in the picture below. I am searching of ideas on how to approach my problem.
!https://www.google.com/search?biw=1347&bih=680&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=_q7BXJ6tBInhkgXB44XIBA&q=ndroid+vertical+time+line&oq=ndroid+vertical+time+line&gs_l=img.3...404393.405025..405582...0.0..0.63.325.7......0....1..gws-wiz-img.mykSprC8u9I#imgrc=6EM_ynLqrPIIkM:

Kind regards 
Todor kosev

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a ListView or ItemsControl where the Item template has line and ellipse on the right with 0 vertical and horizontal margins for the data template.  In this way, you can control the content and the timeline attributes via data binding.

[image]

```
    <ListView x:Name="Timeline">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="60">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Line  X1="15" Stroke="Green" X2="15" Y1="0" Y2="60" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="LightGreen" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                      Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      Margin="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```